# How can I have a column of Radio buttons in Mysql Table

Tags: php, mysql

After much googling to no avail, I am hoping someone can help me figure out how I can create a table of some information where the last column is just a column of radio buttons for each row. Something Like this:

```
ID | First Name | last Name |Select 
1  | John       | Smith     | O (radio button)
```

I basically want user to be able to see the table on their screen and be able to select certain rows using the radio buttons and perform some sort of function like viewing a new table with just that row. I just need help with creating the last column.

Comment: Just store a bool for IsChecked, and then when you bind it checked is $true and unchecked is $false

Comment: Use type set   values are `'0', '1'`    so if row['col']= 1 echo `checked=checked' within the radio input for ON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't store "radio buttons". That's not a datatype.

Think about what a "radio button" is. How does the state of a "radio button" get set on display? And how does state get passed back to the server in a form POST?

A "radio button" has a property named "checked". And that has a value of either TRUE or FALSE.

If we want to store a "radio button" for a row in a database table, what we  really want to store is the state of "checked" property... either TRUE or FALSE.

One way to do that in MySQL is to define a column. We give the column a meaningful name, but for sake of illustration:

```
 radio_button_state TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'boolean'
```

A value of `0` is equivalent to `FALSE`. Any other non-NULL value would be equivalent to `TRUE`.  (And if our column allows for NULL values, a NULL would just be NULL (which is neither TRUE or FALSE.)

There are lots of other ways to implement boolean values in a database column.

Some developers like to store character strings, like 'Y'/'N' or 'T'/'F'. Some developers argue for storing binary types like `BIT`.

But for maximum ease of use and portability, an integer type is the way to go.
This convention of using using integer values for booleans is consistent with MySQL implementation. In evaluating a (boolean) condition, MySQL returns integer value of 0 for FALSE, and integer value of 1 for TRUE.

Again, in terms of evaluating the value stored in the column, in SQL we follow the same convention that MySQL uses:

- a value of 0 evaluates to FALSE.
- a value of 1 evaluates to TRUE
- any non-NULL non-zero value also evaluates to TRUE
- a NULL is just NULL (never TRUE or FALSE)

Comment: I agree, this is probably the best way to go about this. Thanks

Comment: In MySQL, if we define a column using the keyword `BOOLEAN` as the datatype, MySQL uses datatype `TINYINT(1)`.  We add `NOT NULL` if we want to disallow NULL values. In our shop, we always add the UNSIGNED modifier and add a comment that starts with 'boolean'. And we don't ever use `TINYINT(1)` datatype for anything other than  booleans. (We have some other `TINYINT` columns, but we let MySQL assign the default length modifier.)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this :

```
<input type="radio" name ="radio one " checked>
```

checked is optional attributes.